# Able to Connect to vsftpd server using Windows 7, but getting error using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: centos, windows, ftp, vsftpd, filezilla

I tried connecting to my FTP server (vsftpd/CentOS 7/Alibaba Cloud ECS) from my Window 7 system installed on a VirtualBox using FileZilla, and it seems to be working fine.

But in my default system, which is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit) it don't seem to be working. Repeatedly getting the error as below.

I am able to access FTP from my browser in the Ubuntu system though. Not sure why still getting ERRORS when using Filezilla & SSH in the Ubuntu system. Any idea?

**>> Filezilla Error:**
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,84,17).
Command:    LIST
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

**SSH/CLI Error:**
ftp> ls
500 Illegal PORT command.
ftp: bind: Address already in use

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93566/ again.

Comment: @JdeBP - Yes already tried all those solutions, but in vain!